# Cannot find -lQt5Guid and -lQt5Cored

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I am currently trying to compile a Qt application that I [downloaded from github](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled) on my windows machine. I did not have any trouble compiling this on Ubuntu so I was hoping someone could help shed some light on my problem.

I am using Qt-Creator to compile the program.

The exact error messages are:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lQt5Guid
:-1: error: cannot find -lQt5Cored
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My first idea when reading those messages was that the windows PATH variable does not include the locations of the libraries. But when I checked, my PATH contained the following:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin;...
```

Which exists and contains what looks like the correct Dlls.

I am using MingGW rather than the visual studio compiler (although i have it available if needs be).

How can I fix this error and what could be causing it?

**EDIT**: When I run qmake there does not seem to be any problem. The errors come up when I try to build the project.

Comment: Setting PATH will only help at runtime (when you actually start the compiled program), not at buildtime. To find Qt at buildtime is a matter of the used build system. Also, you must use the same compiler (MSVC vs. mingw) used to build Qt.

Comment: What I cannot understand is why its just giving me problems for this project. All the examples im opening from qt creator are building and running without any problem. I have managed to compile this project multiple times on my linux machine - its just giving me problems on windows.

Answer (score 2):

Cored is a fundimental part of Qt so it looks like the linker can't see any of the Qt libraries.

Did you install Qt 5.1.0 SDK?

A few things to check:

1. Do you have a line like this in your .pro file?:

   QT       += core
2. You mentioned "Projects section my path" are you talking about the windows PATH variable? these paths should also be in that. You can check with dos command:

   echo %PATH%

   If these paths are not there, for a test, add them in if this works then something has gone wrong with the local PATH setup (i.e. when running qt creator - if you are using qt creator?)
3. Finally just check that the debug version of the Qt5Cored.dll exists in that folder (C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin) because it looks like you are building a debug build (which is why your program is looking for 'd' post-fixed name Qt5Cored and not Qt5Core).

Comment: The PATH variable was what I was referring to (I updated my question so that its a bit more clear). My PATH variable contains the locations I specified in the question (which contain the correct dlls when I checked). I also just tried compiling the application in release mode but I still got a similar error: `cannot find -lQt5Gui` and `cannot find -lQt5Core`. With regards to adding `QT += core`, i added it to the top level .pro file (This project contains multiple pro files), but it still did not work. I dont think the pro files are the problem because this works on my linux machine.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina did you install using Qt 5.1.0 SDK? and is your project using qtcreator? Or are you running qmake manually?

Comment: I am using Qt-Creator. I installed Qt creator with the SDK (I am pretty sure this the case anyway considering I can compile other example applications just fine).

Comment: I have pasted my compile output onto a gist page. Maybe this would help clear things up? https://gist.github.com/KillaW0lf04/6578113

Comment: humm.... I am wandering if this is a "slash" direction issue. See the comment: "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib/libz.a" -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\\5.1.0\mingw48_32\lib". There are slashes both ways. I have found that windows can be poor at resolving this

Comment: @MichaelAquilina Maybe you can post your .pro file as well just to take a look at.

Comment: There are multiple pro files. Here they are: [1](https://github.com/KillaW0lf04/tiled/blob/master/tiled.pro) [2](https://github.com/KillaW0lf04/tiled/blob/master/src/src.pro) [3](https://github.com/KillaW0lf04/tiled/blob/master/src/tiled/tiled.pro)

Comment: hmm... I can't quite put my finger on the issue here. But you can try this: Get a CMD.exe prompt. CD to the source folder. Then paste the command "g++ -Wl,-s -shared -mthreads -Wl,--out-implib,../../lib/libtiled.a -o ../../lib/tiled.dll object_script.tiled.Release  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib/libz.a" -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\\5.1.0\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core" This should give you the same errors. If this does then we can try to mess around with this line manually and diagnose the issue...

Comment: I got the following error `g++: error: object_script.tiled.Release: No such file or directory`

Comment: ah, you probably need to add whereever that lives into your local cmd.exe path with PATH=%PATH%;<enter path here> better to make a small batch file with a "pause" at the end :)

Comment: Ye I noticed when g++ wasn't being found. I appended where its located to my PATH variable but I dont know where the object in concern is located. Out of curiosity, how did you come up with that command? Was it something in the pro files?

Comment: no, its a copy of the line that failed from the build output. I have a similar line in my qt app build and I can run that on my command line (after add g++ location etc...). So this file object_script.tiled.Release should be located in a folder in your poject somehwere... its a file generated by during the compilation I think. It may be a the level of one of your other sub-.pro file

Comment: The problem seems to be coming from the libtiled sub-project. I tried adding QT += core to the pro file, but this didnt seem to help.

Comment: Something else thats interesting. When I try adding `QT += widgets` to the libtiled pro file, I get the additional error `cannot find -lQt5Widgetsd`.

Comment: Sorry dude, I was not at work today! Yes, none of your Qt libraries are actually being found. Have you compiled any Qt projects with your windows installation? (just to rule out that possibility).

Comment: Failing that... if this is a public access project I could take a quick look at it if you have a link to it.

Comment: I have managed to compile several QT examples from qt creator, its just this project that seems to be giving me problems. The project is indeed public access and is a fork of the project called "tiled". [Here is the link to the fork on github](https://github.com/KillaW0lf04/tiled)

Comment: Ok, I got this project, and with the exception of having to install zlib (which was painful because my IT here really suck and I can't pick my nose without them doing it for me >.< (but I used my linux box to sneak past them :), the build worked.

Comment: I specifically looked for the linker line: `g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o ..\..\automappingconverter.exe debug/main.o debug/converterdatamodel.o debug/convertercontrol.o debug/converterwindow.o debug/moc_converterdatamodel.o debug/moc_converterwindow.o  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -ltiled -LC:/username/Public/code/Qt/build-tiled-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/src/automappingconverter/../../lib -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\\5.1.0\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored`

Comment: I am using a fairly fresh install of Qt 5.1.0 (32 bit) using mingw 4.8 (32 bit). Can you confirm you have the same? If you are able, I would recommend trying this on a fresh install on a different PC, you may somehow have a strange setting with your compiler/Qt... Oh yeah, and I built this via Qt Creator 2.7.2 (not using the command line). All that was installed using QT SDK 5.1.0 mingw 32bit.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Maybe its something wrong with my compiler then. I'm noticing that I have several MinGW Compilers registered in the "Build and Run" tab found in options. One of them uses `g++` and the others seem to use `gcc`. Currently, my QT Kit is using the gcc version. Could you check what you are using? Maybe this is whats causing the problem.

Comment: mm...interesting. I have 5 entries, but they are all the same: `c:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\gcc.exe`. In the kits tab you can see which of these options are being used. Goto "kits" and click the kit (there should be only one unless you added some) and look at the "compiler:" Mine gives the name of the compiler as per the "Compilers" tab page. What is yours setup as?

Comment: Ive tried installing both the Visual Studio 2010 and re-installing the MinGW 4.8 version - still not working for me and I cant figure out why! Perhaps you could give me a pastebin link of your build environment settings?

Comment: yes...I would if I knew what that was (maybe you can explain). But are you installing compilers seperatley?... an idea would be to do a fresh install of the complete Qt 5.1.0 SDK. This install all that you need to build a project (Qt libraries, mingw compiler, qtcreator) and sets them all up to run with each other. It sounds to me like you are trying to do these things seperatley, which of course can be done, but it may be easier to just stick the SDK on there: http://qt-project.org/downloads, I used Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)

Comment: Ye thats the exact same setup file I used :/ Not trying to install anything separately, just using a single setup file. The Build environment can be found by going on the "Projects" tab while you have the project open. If you click on "Details" you should see all your environment variables.

Comment: Oh sorry misunderstood! You can use gist.github.com to paste large amounts of text onto the page and save it. You can then send me the link for me to look at.

Comment: fek..IE does not seem to support gist >.< .. I had to install firefox and then it worked. Here is the link:https://gist.github.com/code-fodder/9af0959e9bec0c9a81f5